# Every https website chrome/IE shows "your connection is not private"

Tags: ssl, https

In the last couple of weeks, one PC here is getting that error for airbnb.com
it is windows 8.1

Now, a new PC that runs Windows 7 Pro is getting the same error for all websites: airbnb, facebook, etc... but not Google

What is possible issue?

Comment: Check with Firefox. If it is ok there the issue is related to the windows certificate store

Comment: Firefox works. whats now?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it definitely needs to be fixed.  Either you have the time and date settings very wrong on both computers, or your connections are being spied on.

Take a look at the certificate: see who provided it/signed it.  Might give you a clue as to what's going on.  Could be someone accidentally enabled HTTPS scanning on your firewall.  The fact that Google doesn't have an SSL error makes me think this is just an accidental firewall configuration. When I had to configure HTTPS scanning for schools, I'd often have to exclude Google from HTTPS scanning and/or web proxies if the client used a lot of services like Google Drive, etc.

Comment: time and date on both are correct

Comment: Yeah, get certificate issuer then.  Go to a page known to have this problem.  In chrome's address bar, click the lock icon with the red X on it.  In the little pop-down, click on "Certificate Information".  A small window should open; Copy/paste whatever is in the "issued by:" field and we could tell you real quick whether that's a valid issuer.

Comment: the issuer is the same on the not working pc and on mine... digicrt (for facebook)

Comment: In that case, on the certificate error page, could you tell me what it gives for the reason under 'Advanced'?

Comment: www.facebook.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Chrome tried to connect to www.facebook.com this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. Either an attacker is trying to pretend to be www.facebook.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.